# sql insert data only in working days

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, insert-into

I have very simple table which construction looks like:

```
id           int
info         varchar
user         varchar
start_date   datatime
end_date     datatime
resources_id int
```

I have to insert many rows (for example for next two years) which will have data only for working days - data from fields are just a simple copy but I don't know how to prepare insert for this kind of specific working days. Is it possible to do that at all?

And my sample dump file looks like that:

```
id   info   user     start_date            end_date              resource_id
31   NULL   aorlik   2018-01-04 08:00:00   2018-01-04 10:00:00   1
32   NULL   aorlik   2018-01-04 15:00:00   2018-01-04 17:00:00   1
```

Comment: I use MySQL language

Comment: do you want to create a `sql script file` (which contains all sql commands) with all the dates? Or do you want to create a script that inserts its directly into the table. You could make a MYSQL function to do so, or use something like python, php, etc.

Comment: i just want to insert this data only one time so it's really doesn't matter what kind of approach i will use to do that... easiest way is always the best:)

Comment: Hi. You are not clear. What does "prepare insert for this kind of specific working days" mean? Use enough words to say what you mean. Edit your post, comments are not for clarifications.

Comment: Where is your data currently?  In one file or several files?  Local to the database, or on some remote machine, or the cloud?  Is the source data in datetime order, or does it need to be searched?  Has the source data been validated, or could a column have some dubious values in it?  It appears to be tab-delimited?  What about escaping/encoding for any strings that include tabs or quotes, etc?  This question is currently so vague as to be impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

I create a database function that create a whole year of dates. You can finetune it according to your wishes, but you should get the idea.

It basically loops over all the days in the year, if the day happens be a `sat` or `sun`, it skips the date. You can changes this how you like.

For this to work I created a test table with 2 datetime fields (start_date, end_date). Inside the function I truncate the table, just for testing purpose.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS create_date_for_year;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE create_date_for_year (IN year INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE day INT DEFAULT 1;

    SET day=1;

    TRUNCATE test; -- JUST FOR TESTING!

    WHILE day < 366 DO  
        IF WEEKDAY(MAKEDATE(year, day)) NOT IN (5,6) THEN -- skip sat and sun
            INSERT INTO TEST (start_date, end_date) VALUES ( 
                CONCAT(MAKEDATE(year, day), ' ', MAKETIME(8,0,0)),
                CONCAT(MAKEDATE(year, day), ' ', MAKETIME(10,0,0))
                );
        END IF;
        SET day = day + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;

//

CALL create_date_for_year(2018)
```

Comment: The OP has slightly clarified their situation : They have a dump file (or files) with data to be bulk-inserted in to their table.  But there are quite a few other ambiguities.